# loop whole code many times on SAS program causes error

Tags: loops, sas, sas-macro

I have a long code about 5000 lines. When I macro this program, and loop a few times. It executed successfully but if I changed the loop to 300 times, the code started to cause the error, I can not figure out why it causes,

```
%let Numberl=300;

%macro programall;
%do r=0 %to &numberl;
.
.
.
.
.
%end;
%mend Programall;
%Programall;
```

I assume sleep function may stop this problem
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0a6vn2td7bjr2n1viy8y4lgvq61.htm

Does anybody have a similar experience?

sorry about my English

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the code, it should run fine. However, there might be some issues within the do block.. not sure what you are trying to do there ..

Comment: With what you’ve shown here we can’t say. Your code could be wrong, it could be right. Can you generate an example that creates the error? And include the error please!

Comment: Maybe log size issue? You could try to print to external file: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001330273.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside the loop is likely not resetting important macro variables it is using or there are nested macro calls that are using macro variables that are not properly declared as `%local` in their `%macro` definition.

When ever you code a macro, make sure the variables it uses are declared at the top as such as follows:

```
%macro foo(top=);
  %local index piece1 piece2;
  %do index = 1 %to &top;
    %let piece1 = …;
  %end;
%mend;
```

Is there a consistent specific value of `&r` at which the failure occurs?  If so, you may have suppositions about `r` that are incorrect.

You can see what macro is generating by setting options before invoking `%programall`.  These options will log **a lot** of information at the most detailed level:

```
options mprint mtrace symbolgen;
```

You can save the actual code that macro generates to an external file using `mfile`.

```
filename mfile 'c:\temp\300-at-Thermopylae.sas';
options mprint mfile;

%programall

%options nomfile;
```

Note: The problem might be in the generated source code, or in the generation process it self.  You can examine the saved `.sas` file for problems, and submit pieces of it individually, in order to locate where things have gone astray.

Answer (score 0):

SO, I found out that there is comment like this in the code between the loop

```
*********GPA's something;
```

I took off  '  then started run perfect. It was comment but Macro seems takes as string

Thanks

Comment: You cannot have unbalanced quotes in statement style comments if they are embedded in a macro definition.  The SAS processor can handle the comment statements ok, but they end up confusing the macro processor when embedded in a macro definition so the wrong code is sent to SAS to execute.